# Android RunOnUIThread Isnt permenantly changing View visibility

Tags: java, android, view

Im trying to call a function from within a doInBackground of an `AsyncTask` that fades in a progressBar. Everytime i call this function the progressbar fades in as required then disappears. I added a check at the end which tells me that the visibility of the progressbar has returned back to `GONE` as soon as the `runOnUIThread` method completes:

> Reset Prog To Gone

Why is this and how can I make it so the progressbar remains visible?

I have been using the following:

```
    @TargetApi(12)
    private void fadeInProgressBar(final int time, ProgressBar prog){
        System.out.println("MainActivity: Fading In ProgressBar");
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if(usingHigherApiThan(12)&&prog.getVisibility()==View.GONE){
                    prog.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    if(prog.getAlpha()<1){
                        prog.animate().setDuration(time).alpha(1);
                    }
                }else if(prog.getVisibility()==View.GONE){
                    prog.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    final AlphaAnimation animation = new AlphaAnimation(0F, 1F);
                    animation.setDuration(time);
                    animation.setFillAfter(true);
                    prog.startAnimation(animation);
                }

            }
        });

        if(prog.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE){
            System.out.println("Left Prog Visible");
        }else{
            System.out.println("Reset Prog To Gone");
        }
    }
```

note `usingHigherApiThan(12)` just checks the build version is 12 or greater and this problem occurs for both above 12 and below 11.

Comment: "I added a check at the end ... as soon as the runOnUIThread method completes" No, the `runOnUiThread` code is executed in parallel or in the future, what you print there is the state at the beginning /before the animation. If it disappears after the animation it's probably your code doing that. Animations don't reset the state back once done.

Comment: @zapl I probably should have noticed. Regardless of this the progressBar is still set to View.GONE after the runonuithread completes

Comment: Check if you do `setVisibility(View.GONE)` somewhere else. Animations don't do that and code in `runOnUiThread` is done at the beginning of the animation. It justs starts it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to, and probably shouldn't, do it this way. `AsyncTask` has methods that run on the `UI` thread already (all but `doInBackground()`)

Put your code that you want to run on the `UI` into `onPostExecute()` to run when `doInBackground()` has finished.

Or if it suits your needs better you can also put the code in `onProgressUpdate()` and call this function when needed with `publishProgress()`.

Alternatively, if you only need it to run when the task starts then you can just put it in `onPreExecute()`. All of these run on the `UI Thread`. There's no need to add extra steps with `runOnUiThread()`.

[AsyncTask Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Comment: This is an option but would mean reorganizing a lot of code. I was just wondering if there was a method i could call on the Runnable rather like the setFillAfter on the Animation that permanently changes the View

Comment: If your code is all in the one function then there won't be that much reorganizing. If it is called multiple times then you put this code in the `onProgressUpdate()` function and replace your function calls with a `publishProgress()` call. If it only happens each time the task runs then simply put this code in one of the other two functions and you don't have to make any calls.